# Data returned as undefined in ngOnInit() but not in function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I'm returning data from an API and I've put in several `console.log()` statements for debugging. In the `ngOnInit()`, the `console.log` is printing `undefined`, but in the separate function the `console.log` returns the correct data and in theory, no other processing is done in between.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAnimalList('fur');
    console.log(this.animalsFur);
  }

  loadAnimalList(classification: string) {
    this.animalService.getAnimals(classification).subscribe((animals: Animal[]) => {
      switch (classification) {
        case 'fur':
          this.animalsFur = animals;
          break;
        case 'feather':
          this.animalsFeather = animals;
          break;
        case 'scales':
          this.animalsScales = animals;
          break;
        case 'other':
          this.animalsOther = animals;
          break;
        default:
          this.animalsFur = animals;
          break;
      }
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error, 'Failed to Load Animals...');
    });
  }
```

The console.log I've left in id the one that returns undefined, if I put one (for example) after the switch is complete, or in case statement then the correct data is shown in the console, just not in the onInit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `getAnimals` is asynchronous. That's why `console.log(this.animalsFur);` returns undefined, as `getAnimals` has not finished running when the console statement is called. You should read up more about JavaScript's [event loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), if you want to gain more context about it.

On the other hand, calling the `console` statement within `subscribe` will ensure that the `animalsFur` property is assigned with the value from the response, as the block of code within `subscribe` will only run after the observable from `getAnimals()` is returned.

```
this.animalService.getAnimals(classification).subscribe((animals: Animal[]) => {
  switch (classification) {
    case 'fur':
      this.animalsFur = animals;
      break;
    case 'feather':
      this.animalsFeather = animals;
      break;
    case 'scales':
      this.animalsScales = animals;
      break;
    case 'other':
      this.animalsOther = animals;
      break;
    default:
      this.animalsFur = animals;
      break;
  }
  // the below should be defined
  console.log(animals);
  // this should be defined as long classification === 'fur', or if the switch statement hits default case
  console.log(this.animalsFur);
}, error => {
  this.alertify.error(error, 'Failed to Load Animals...');
});
```